# SQL - Sum Column until Other Column Condition

Tags: sql

I have a table with three columns:

`employee_id`, `days`, `sales`

`employee_id` isn't unique because it repeats for different combinations of days and sales.

I'd like to produce a table with three columns:

`employee_id`, `sales - 30`, `sales - final`

where:

`employee_id` is now unique,

`sales - 30` = sum(sales) (where days <= 30), and

`sales - final` = sum(sales) per ID.

Here's a before/after what I'm looking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Example images are linked below!

[before image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAyMH.jpg)

[after image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUeCj.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `conditional aggregation` for this:

```
select employee_id,
       sum(case when days <= 30 then sales end) as sales30,
       sum(sales) as allsales
from yourtable
group by employee_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        Select empid , sum (sales)  as total ,
         sum (case when days <=30 then sales else 0 end ) as sales_30 
        from SALES_DATA 
         GROUP BY empid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Select empid , sum (sales)  as total ,
         sum (case when days <=30 then sales  
        else 0 end ) as sales_30 
        from SALES_DATA 
         GROUP BY empid
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can try this

WITH sale30 AS (SELECT employee_id,SUM(sale) sale 
WHERE day<=30 GROUP BY employee_id),
saleFinal AS (SELECT employee_id,SUM(sale) sale 
GROUP BY employee_id)
SELECT sf.employee_id,s3.sale sale_30,sf.sale
FROM salefinal sf, sale30 s3
WHERE sf.employee_id=s3.employee_id(+)

In general you can use this

SELECT sf.employee_id,s3.sale sale_30,sf.sale
FROM (SELECT employee_id,SUM(sale) sale 
GROUP BY employee_id) sf, (SELECT employee_id,SUM(sale) sale 
WHERE day<=30 GROUP BY employee_id) s3
WHERE sf.employee_id=s3.employee_id(+)